# what is a variable 'name' of javascript?

Tags: javascript

for example,

```
var name = [1,2,3]  // name === "1,2,3"
name = {"a":"b"}  // name === "[object Object]"
```

I don't understand this situation.

what is the identity of 'name' or 'window.name' on javascript?

ADD:

I used Chrome's Dev Tools

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/) and [this](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Comment: From **where** did you get those values? Firefox's native console? An alert? If you use Chrome's Dev Tools or Firebug it'll display the object's properties, and give a proper representation of the array.

Comment: I used Chrome's Dev Tools. but it's different from another variable.

Comment: @Ephemera what do you mean "different" and "another variable"?

Comment: If you use another variable, such as not 'name', then it is normal.( var a = [1, 2, 3] // a !== "1,2,3", a === [1,2,3])

Comment: I mean just focus on 'name' or 'window.name'

Comment: In browser's JavaScript, all "global" variable are under the  `window` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare

```
name = {"a":"b"}
```

you are creating an object and the string representation of an object is `[object Object]`, that is, when you try to convert an object to a string (which is probably the case here) you get that result.

Note that `name === "[object Object]"` is *not* true.

```
alert( name === "[object Object]" );             // alerts "false"
alert( name.toString() === "[object Object]" );  // alerts "true"
```

The same holds true for the array. `1,2,3` is just a string representation of array `[1,2,3]`.

---

As for `window.name`, it has the name of the current window so changing it to a non-string might lead to unexpected behavior: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.name

Comment: String representation.. You could also add that whatever way OP is displaying these "values" is forcing them to be cast to strings.

Comment: You may like to state that `typeof name` is to be used for type checking rather than using `name.toString()` to avoid confusion

Comment: @AlvinWong I thought about it, but it might be confusing in this case since `typeof [1,2,3] === 'object'`.

Comment: Firebug is fine. You are right. but try on Chrome's Dev Tool. It's a little strange.

Comment: @Ephemera What exactly is strange about it?

Comment: If you use another variable, such as not 'name', then it is normal.( var a = [1, 2, 3] // a !== "1,2,3", a === [1,2,3])

Comment: I've added that to the answer.

Comment: @Ephemera because `window.name` is supposed to be a string. Some engine may automatically convert it to a string.

Comment: This is also a good reason why you should avoid global variables.

Comment: @AlvinWong I think you are right. Just Chrome's policy(?) is reason. Thanks every body.